# How can I get my APU to work as it should?

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics

I have recently installed L18.04.4 LTS installed with its 5.3 kernel on my laptop; after switching though multiple distros I found that Ubuntu suits me best. But there is a problem.

It seems like my drivers for the APU don't work as they should. I tried to install AMDGPU / PRO but the performance was terrible.

Also it says that the VRAM is at 512Mb but it should be at 2Gb.

How can I get it to work properly?

[image: Image with info.]

Added picture of lshw output. The information about the GPU is wrong.

[image: LSHW OUTPUT]

Comment: @K7AAY I just added the info. Thank your for the heads up!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, Ideapad S340 Ryzen 7 3700U 81N overview tells the GPU shares RAM on board, so what else is the problem?

Comment: Hello, yes indeed the GPU shares RAM with the board. But you can set from the bios how much RAM it allocates. It's set to 2 gb. But that does not seem to affect it in the OS. How can I let it dynamically allocate memory up to 2 gb or set the value to 2 GB